# PHP timestring to DateTime don't give correct result

Tags: php, datetime

I have a timestring comming from an XML File

```
1408226400
```

Now i want to convert this string into an `DateTime` object, but i'm getting the wrong result.

```
//This is an example for this Question, but with the real datestring
//My real code looks like this: $dbTurn->setStartDate(new \DateTime("@".$turn['cruiseStartDateString']));

$test = date("d-m-Y H:i", 1408226400);
$dateTime = new DateTime($test);
print_r($dateTime);
# result is DateTime Object ( [date] => 2014-08-16 18:00:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => America/New_York )
```

But that is  not the date i expected, because the result i should because is this:

```
2014-08-17 10:04:00
```

Also, taken from the real code i mentioned in the comment within the code, this snippet:

```
$dbTurn->setStartDate(new \DateTime($turn['cruiseStartDateString']));
```

Throws this error if i don't suppress the error message:

```
message => (string) DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (1408226400) at position 7 (4): Unexpected character
```

Is something wrong with the datestring or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: this is because of your timezone. set your timezone first.

Comment: the result is correct. Check out this tool: http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm

Comment: @i-CONICA so there may be more than one problem: the date he mentioned ("2014-08-17 10:04:00") doesn't match with 1408226400, no matter which time zone.

Comment: @SKRocks i tried `$dateTime = new DateTime($test, new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'));` now, but the result is nearly the same: `DateTime Object ( [date] => 2014-08-16 18:00:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Berlin )`. Or do i need to set it in a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
$test = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", 1408226400);
$dateTime = new DateTime($test);
print_r($dateTime);
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2014-08-17 12:00:00
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
)
```

Comment: I would never mix `date()` and `DateTime`. And this code will not work if time is >12hour, because format `h` is `12-hour format of an hour with leading zeros`.

Comment: change the format as `Y-m-d H:i:s` or `Y-m-d h:i:s A` or you can change format as you want see http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to create a formatted datestring using date() before passing to a DateTime object constructor:

```
$timestamp = 1408226400;

$dateTime = new DateTime('@' . $timestamp);
print_r($dateTime);
```

though you may also need to pass a timezone to the DateTime constructor as well